# Does $f(t) \le \int_0^t (t-s)^{-\frac{1}{2}} [f(s) + |f(s)|^{\beta}] \, \mathrm d s$ imply $f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

Let $\beta \in (0, 1)$. We assume $f : [0, 1] \to [0, \infty)$ is a measurable and bounded function such that
$$
f(t) \le \int_0^t (t-s)^{-\frac{1}{2}} [f(s) + |f(s)|^{\beta}] \, \mathrm d s,
\quad \forall t \in [0, 1].
$$

> I would like to ask if $f=0$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$ f(t) = \varepsilon t^A$$
will be a counterexample if $\varepsilon>0$ is small enough and $A > 1$ is large enough (one basically needs $A \beta + 1/2 \leq A$ and $\varepsilon \leq \varepsilon^\beta \int_0^1 (1-s)^{-1/2} s^A\ ds$).

Comment: I am sad that it is not true but thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: One can compare with the initial value problem $f'(t) = f(t)^\beta, f(0)=0$ (or equivalently $f(t) = \int_0^t f(s)^\beta\ ds$), which famously has a non-trivial solution $f(t) = C t^{\frac{1}{1-\beta}}$ where $C = (1-\beta)^{1/(1-\beta)}$ when $0 < \beta < 1$.

Comment: @TerryTao , Can we utilize the Banach fixed-point theorem, to approach that problem ?